# How to check if text file is already added or opened

Tags: c#

I would like to open and add a text file content into a list Box, but if I want to add another text file, how do I check if the file that I add is already added into the list Box. I mean I don't want the list box to be duplicated.

```
private void openAndAddToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Text file|*.txt";
    openFileDialog.Title = "Open Text";
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(openFileDialog.OpenFile()))

        {
            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                donutListBox.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside form checking the listbox for duplicates, if you want to realise that you've already opened the file earlier to extract values, you could maintain a collection of the visited files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an if:

```
if ( !donutListBox.Items.Contains(line) ){
    donutListBox.Items.Add(line);
}
```

Comment: @HungNguyen So don't forget to accept the answer please.

Answer (score 1):

If you on .net framework 4+, you can use `File.ReadAllLines(string filename)` static method:

```
private void openAndAddToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Text file|*.txt";
    openFileDialog.Title = "Open Text";
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog.FileName);
        lines = lines.Where(line => !donutListBox.Items.Contains(line)).ToArray();
        donutListBox.Items.AddRange(lines);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try is

```
public static bool IsFileInUse(string filename)
{
  bool locked = false;
  try
  {
    FileStream fs =
    File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
    FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    fs.Close();
  }
  catch (IOException ex)
  {
    locked = true;
  } 
 return locked;
}
```

And :

```
if(!Class.IsFileInUse("FilePAth") && !donutListBox.Items.Contains(line))
{
     //your code
}
```